# Changing if a div's class if unable to ping a url. (Test if a site is down)

Tags: javascript, html

I have been researching this for a while. For the site static.etreeblog.com I would like to change a duv's class if a website is offline.

Ways I have researched:

-Using the onerror tag with an image to run a function. 
-Problem: One of the sites i want to test uses an external image host, meaning even if the site was offline the image could be.

Example of what I want to do:

```
function checksite( site, url ){
if url == online {
document.getElementByClass('site').setClass('online')
}
}

checksite('site1', 'www.example.com')
checksite('site2, 'www.example2.com')
```

Thankyou in advance.

Extra information: 
-The divs will be set to offline by default.
-I am using tumblr to host the status tester (If that helps).

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP, Its a solid way to do this.

Host this script on your server (file name say **test.php**)

```
<?php 
$url = $_REQUEST["url"];
$port = $_REQUESR["port"]; // Or make it default
$fp = fsockopen($url, $port, $errno, $errstr, 0.4); //(line 47)
if (!$fp) {
  echo "OFFLINE";
}
else{
 echo "ONLINE";
}
?>
```

Now loop AJAX to open this file and check whether it is echoing ONLINE or OFFLINE.

Comment: I need it doing in html/javascript. Is there a way to try to load another part of the page with javascript?

Comment: What you could is make a AJAX request to a URL, and set a timeout, if it respond back in the timeout then it is alive or else it is dead. According to me the Image way is more robust then the AJAX Way.

Comment: The only image hosted on the site is http://www.etreeblog.com/favicon.ico, could i use a script to load the favicons of the websites?

Answer (score 0):

You will need help on the server side.  You could do an AJAX call to your server and it will call the url and return with the site status.  If it is that server your monitoring then the AJAX error code will tell you the status.